# Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32 Broken pipe IN SPRING mvc rest service

Tags: spring

How to set connection timeout to only particular to that rest spring mvc request.

I want to render huge data of clothes on browser but server send an connection timeout error.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/clothes/{clothType}/properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Clothes> getClothesList(@PathVariable String clothType, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Clothes> listClothes;
    try {
        listClothes = ClothesApiService.getClothesProperties(clothType); 

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.info("Problem getting the properties for Clothes " + clothType + ". Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return listClothes;
}
```

Below is stack trace on IBM server logs

> at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1613) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      128      at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:140) ~[org.springframework.web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>      129      ... 49 common frames omitted
>      130  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe
>      131      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.(AsyncLibrary.java:891) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      132      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      133      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      134      at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:473) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      135      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:478) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      136      at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.write(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:396) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      137      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.writeAIO(AioSocketIOChannel.java:282) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      138      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.processAsyncWriteRequest(AioTCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:53) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      139      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.writeInternal(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:382) ~[na:CC70.CF [a0849.02]]
>      140      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.write(TCPWriteRequestContextImpl.java:353) ~[na:CC70.CF [a0849.02]]
>      141      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.asynchWrite(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2442) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      142      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.sendOutgoing(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:2229) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      143      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.sendResponseBody(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:866) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
>      144      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferAsynch(WCChannelLink.java:551) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      145      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBufferResponse(WCChannelLink.java:528) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      146      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.writeBuffer(WCChannelLink.java:472) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      147      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.flushWriteBuffer(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:406) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      148      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.checkWriteArray(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:378) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      149      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:111) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      150      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      151      at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.writeOut(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:569) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      152      at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.flushBytes(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:433) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      153      at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.BufferedServletOutputStream.write(BufferedServletOutputStream.java:383) ~[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
>      154      at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      155      at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.writeString(Utf8Generator.java:561) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      156      at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:28) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      157      at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      158      at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446) ~[jackson-all-1.9.11.jar:1.9.11]
>      159      ... 58 common frames omitted

Below is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/clothes/{clothType}/properties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Clothes> getClothesList(@PathVariable String clothType, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Clothes> listClothes;
    try {
        listClothes = ClothesApiService.getClothesProperties(clothType); 

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.info("Problem getting the properties for Clothes " + clothType + ". Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return listClothes;
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue - using spring 5.3.13 and IBM WAS 9.0 version and JDK 1.8 - Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 32  Broken pipe
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:924) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:937) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?] 
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:951) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]